# Azure ADB2C - Invitation lifetime

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I thought this would be a simple Google but I cant seem to find an answer.

When an invitation email is sent from Azure AD B2C (Active Directory Business to Consumer), how long is the emailed link valid for before it can no longer be redeemed?

Is this configurable anywhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To invite a user, from the application, we will type the user's email address and click Send invintation.  The application sends a sign-in link (with a id_token_hint). User clicks on the link, that takes to user to Azure AD B2C policy.
The key to sending data to Azure AD B2C custom policy is to package the data into a JWT token as claims using id_token_hint. In this case, we send the user's email address to Azure B2C. Sending JWT token requires to host the necessary metadata endpoints required to use the "id_token_hint" parameter in Azure AD B2C. The id_token_hint must be a valid JWT token. The token contains the claims that are mandatory.

**So inside the token we have claim called exp(Expiration time): The time at which the token becomes invalid, represented in epoch time. Azure AD B2C validates this value, and rejects the token if the token is expired.**

[Token Format and claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/id-token-hint#token-format)

[Reference](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/invite/README.md)